# RadGridView Items not updating with ItemsSource changed inside a TabItem

Tags: radgridview, tabitem, itemssource

I have an Grid inside a tabItem with is not focused in Windows_Load / Constructor, and if i feed the ItemsSource property, the Items property continues with 0 until i go to the tabItem.
I guess its something wrong with the renderization.

Here is the code:

```
IList<ProdutosProxy> lstProxy = ProdutosProxy.RetornarDadosProdutos(lstProdutos);
    this.grdProdutosEservicos.ItemsSource = lstProxy;
    this.grdProdutosEservicos.Items.Refresh();
```

The ItemsSource gets 1 item, but the Items continues with 0 until i focus the tabItem.
Already tried Rebind() and UpdateLayout().

Someone know something about that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem..
Just forced the update on Window_Loaded from tab/grid and goes back to original tab.

```
    private void AtualizarGrid(String gridHeader)
    {
        for (var tabIndex = tabControl1.Items.Count - 1; tabIndex >= 0; tabIndex--)
        {
            if ((tabControl1.Items[tabIndex] as TabItem).Header.ToString() == gridHeader)
            {
                tabControl1.SelectedIndex = tabIndex;
                tabControl1.UpdateLayout();
            }
        }
    }
```